# redirect the entire php url with params (apache/nginx)

Tags: apache, url, redirect, nginx

1) How to make Apache to redirect the whole url with parameters, and make it visible to a client, for example:
when client comes to :

```
https://domain1.com/app/index.php?device_id=WeWeWe&ordna_ver=5.0&num=+1234567890
```

it redirects him to:

```
https://domain2.com/app/index.php?device_id=WeWeWe&ordna_ver=5.0&num=+1234567890
```

2) Also, how to make the same redirect but NOT visible to a client (he still see the URL from domain1.com while opening it from domain2.com) ?

3) And the third, how to make the same two things (redirects) with nginx ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In nginx, visible to the client:

```
server_name domain1.com;
return https://domain2.com$request_uri;
```

In nginx, hiding the redirect from being visible to the client:

```
server_name domain1.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://domain2.com;
}
```

You might also want to use the optional module http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter (requires recompilation of nginx), if you want to make sure to replace any mention of `domain2.com` from the proxied web-page with `domain1.com`.

```
sub_filter "https://domain1.com" "https://domain2.com";
sub_filter_once off;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to make the same with Apache2 ?